# How do I ensure that only one instance of my ksh script runs on Solaris using NFS?

Tags: solaris, ksh, nfs, lock

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What Unix commands can be used as a semaphore/lock?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70/what-unix-commands-can-be-used-as-a-semaphore-lock)

I have read many similar post and the solution seems to be to use flock. flock does not exist on my system and I don't have rights to add it.

**References:**

1. A "BashFAQ" link provided in a comment in [how-to-make-sure-only-one-instance-of-a-bash-script-runs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48505/how-to-make-sure-only-one-instance-of-a-bash-script-runs) talks about using [flock](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/045)

Comment: [How about Perl?](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=7058) Besides, [the *lock directory* solution](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/48510/11539) is available.

Comment: @sr_ Yes I do have Perl! For portability I am hoping to avoid dependency on external programs..

Comment: Anyway, I'm rather confused about your question, since *none* of the answers in the referenced question uses `flock`...

Comment: @sr_ Sorry about that.. flock was mentioned in a comment.

Comment: @sr_ and others: note that this question specifically asks about NFS. Many NFS implementations have race conditions that break many locking techniques. Solaris's NFS implementation is better than most, but please do not close this question as a duplicate of one that doesn't focus on NFS. Kent: are all the clients and the server running Solaris?

Answer (score -3):

Is simple a lock file, created with touch or echo, too weak for you system?

Comment: That results in the much talked about race condition.