# Shell Script while loop: [ around a pipeline missing `]'

Tags: linux, shell-script, scripting

The shell script I'm trying to use keeps giving this error:

```
$ ./script.sh: line 2: [: missing `]' 
grep: ]: No such file or directory
```

The line is part of a section trying to check if a particular process is going to have a file locked:

```
COUNTER=0
while [ ps aux | grep "[r]elayevent.sh" ] && [ "$COUNTER" -lt 10 ]; do
    sleep 3
    let COUNTER+=1
done
```

Obviously I've checked that the brackets all pair up correctly - which looks fine to me. Also the common white space around the condition issue doesn't apply.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Note for the future. Whenever you get a syntax error, run - don't walk - straight to https://shellcheck.net/ and paste in the block of your code that exhibits the issue.

Comment: You should use `flock` command to implement locks in scripts.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error is that you should remove first `[` because of you want to check the exit status then use command directly.

The Wiki pages of the [Shellcheck tool](https://www.shellcheck.net/) have an explanation for this ([issue SC1014](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC1014)):

> `[ .. ]` is not part of shell syntax like `if` statements. It is not equivalent to parentheses in C-like languages, `if (foo) { bar; }`, and should not be wrapped around commands to test.
>
> `[` is just regular command, like `whoami` or `grep`, but with a funny name (see `ls -l /bin/[`). It's a shorthand for `test`.
>
> If you want to check the exit status of a certain command, use that command directly.
>
> If you want to check the output of a command, use `"$(..)"` to get its output, and then use `test` or `[`/`[[` to do a string comparison:

Also use `ps aux | grep -q "[r]elayevent.sh"` so that you will get the exit status silently instead of printing anything to `stdout`.

Or you can use `pgrep` and direct it's output to `/dev/null`.

Use second condition first because it will be more efficient for the last case.

So final script will be like:

```
#!/bin/bash
COUNTER=0

while [ "$COUNTER" -lt 10 ] && ps aux | grep -q "[r]elayevent.sh"   ; do

    sleep 3

    let COUNTER+=1

done
```

Or

```
#!/bin/bash
COUNTER=0

while [ "$COUNTER" -lt 10 ] && pgrep  "[r]elayevent.sh" >/dev/null  ; do

    sleep 3

    let COUNTER+=1

done
```

Comment: You probably want to add `-q` when calling `grep`, too.  Otherwise it prints the matching lines.

Comment: @Mikel thanks, it will silently give status instead of printing anything.

Comment: You should mention where that quote is from. Also, `grep -q "[r]elayevent.sh"` doesn't make much sense, and `ps | grep` is usually better replaced with `pgrep`; but the `let COUNTER+=1` is fine in `bash`, `zsh` and `ksh39` (`((..))` is not a bit more portable)  -- though the whole script doesn't make much sense ;-)).

Comment: I would swap the tests around to avoid running `grep` on the last iteration.

Comment: That is more efficient.

Comment: That's perfect, works exactly as I wanted. Thanks so much for the thorough explanation.

Answer (score 4):

You can't have a pipe inside `[ ... ]`.  It's also better to use `pgrep` than to try to parse the output of `ps`:

```
count=0
while [ "$count" -lt 10 ] && pgrep relayevent.sh >/dev/null; then
    sleep 3
    count=$(( count + 1 ))
done
```

BSD systems could use `pgrep -q ...` instead of `pgrep ... >/dev/null` to discard the actual output of `pgrep`, just as with ordinary `grep` (we're only interested in the exit status).

Note how we don't put the `pgrep` command within `[ ... ]`.  That's because we're not interested in its output, only its exit status.  With `[ ... ]` you commonly compare strings or numbers.  The `[ ... ]` will result in an exit status that is zero (true) or non-zero (false), just like the `pgrep` execution.

However, this does not check for any locking mechanisms, only whether a particular process is running or not.

If you are trying to get only a single instance of a script running, then it's better to do something like this (assuming the `EXIT` trap is executed whenever the script is terminating orderly):

```
lockdir=dir.lock

if mkdir "$lockdir"; then
    trap 'rmdir "$lockdir"' EXIT
else
    echo 'Only one instance of this script allowed' >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

With a number of tries and sleep:

```
lockdir=dir.lock

count=0
while [ "$count" -lt 10 ]; then
    if mkdir "$lockdir"; then
        trap 'rmdir "$lockdir"' EXIT
        break
    else
        echo 'Locked. Sleeping...' >&2
        sleep 3
    fi

    count=$(( count + 1 ))
done

if [ "$count" -eq 10 ]; then
    echo 'Giving up.' >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Related:

- [How to make sure only one instance of a bash script runs?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48505)

Comment: I also thought of pgrep but didn't thought of `/dev/null`.

Comment: @PRY `pgrep` on BSD systems have a `-q` option to avoid that particular ugliness. It works just as with `grep`.

Comment: @PRY you could use `pkill -0 ...` instead of `pgrep ... >/dev/null`