# How to make sure only one instance of a bash script with parameters runs?

Tags: bash

if I have a `deployment.sh`, it has two parameters: environment and release version.

```
deployment.sh uat release1
deployment.sh prod release1
```

I want to make at any time: the `deployment.sh` with same environment and release version can be run in singleton.
But  `deployment.sh uat release1` and `deployment.sh prod release1` can be run concurrently.

How to do this.
Thx

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48505/how-to-make-sure-only-one-instance-of-a-bash-script-runs?rq=1 for more ideas.

Answer (score 5):

One way of doing this is file locking which is explicitly for picking just one among several processes. See `man flock`:

```
#! /bin/bash

category="$1"
if [ 'uat' != "$category" ] && [ 'prod' != "$category" ]; then
    exit 2
fi

(
    flock -n 9 || exit 1
    # ... commands executed under lock ...
) 9>/var/lock/"$category"
```

Comment: `flock` is the most reliable solution I know too in this use case