# Running pidof in a function

Tags: bash, shell-script, pidof

I want to detect whether my script is already running, so I use [this](/revisions/398710/2):

```bash
pidof -o %PPID -x "$0" >/dev/null && echo 'already running!' && exit 1
```

That works. But I want it in a function:

```bash
#!bin/bash
set -eu
set -o pipefail

checkIfRunning() {
  pidof -o %PPID -x "$0" >/dev/null && echo 'already running!' && exit 1
}

#...

checkIfRunning
```

That doesn't work: it always exits even if only one instance of the script is running.

I thought that if `pidof` were running in a subshell that it would detect the subshell and the script, and thus explain the result - but I don't see how a subshell is created here?

What is the reason for this, and how do I fix it?

Comment: How are you starting the script?

Comment: @Kusalananda `./myscript.sh`. Are you implying the above should work and the problem is elsewhere?

Comment: Beware that in several shells, `$0` inside a function expands to the name of the function. Something to bear in mind if you intend to switch to another shell in the future. Having `SCRIPTNAME=$0` at the start of the script and refer to that instead would make your script more portable.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Something new I didn't know - do you recall which shells that applies to? I only use "common" ones, but it's good to beware.

Comment: @lonix zsh (when not in sh emulation) and ksh at least though in ksh (ksh93 and mksh at least), that only applies to functions declared with the `function f { ...;}` syntax.

Comment: `man set` says that *The  `-e` setting shall be ignored when executing the compound list following the while, until, if, or elif reserved word (...) **or any command of an AND-OR list other than the last**.* -- I read this as: "`set -e` will not react to anything in a `&&`-chain except the last command", which in this case simply exits 1 (successfully).

Comment: @pzkpfw, there's no standalone `set` command. It seems on your system `set` man page documents the `set` special builtin of some POSIX-like shell, or maybe it's actually the POSIX specification of the special `set` `sh` builtin. Here, the OP would want to look at the documentation of their own shell. Like `info bash set` for `bash` or `info zsh errexit` for `zsh`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code with `set -e` (short for `set -o errexit`) unhandled command failures cause the shell to exit.

`pidof` returns with a failure exit status when no matching process is found, but you do handle that failure. `pidof` is used as part of a *and-or list*, so its failure does *not* trigger `errexit`.

However because you used an *and-or list* where you should have used a `if` construct, the `pidof && othercommand` itself exits with a non-zero exit status and because that and-or list is the last thing run in the `checkIfRunning` function, the `checkIfRunning` function itself will also return with a failure exit status.

And that failure is not handled, so `errexit` is triggered. `errexit` is triggered not because `pidof` fails but because `checkIfRunning` failed.

Here, you should have written:

```
checkIfRunning() {
  if pidof -o %PPID -x -- "$0" >/dev/null; then
    echo >&2 'Already running!'
    exit 1
  fi
}
```

The exit status of a `if` construct is that of the last command run in the `then` or `else` part or `0` if none was run, not the exit status of the condition part.

Generally, replacing `if` constructs with and-or lists is *wrong*. Besides the problem of the overall exit status, if `echo` fails in your `pidof && echo && exit 1`, the script doesn't exit.

I'd argue that as soon as you use functions or anything other than the simplest script, `errexit` should be  avoided and proper error handling be done.

See [the corresponding section about `set -euo pipefail` in the bash wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#set_-euo_pipefail) (short for `set -o errexit -o nounset -o pipefail`) or [this FAQ entry](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105).

Regarding [your (now deleted) answer](/q/710062) which tried to address the problem with:

> ```
> checkIfRunning() {
>   set +e                              # <---
>   pidof -o %PPID -x $0 >/dev/null \
>     && echo "running!" && exit 1
>   set -e                              # <---
> }
> ```

The only reason it works is because `set -e` happens to exit with a success status, so `checkIfRunning` does as well, the `set +e` is irrelevant and not needed, `set -e` could have been replaced with `true` or `return 0`.

Comment: Moral of the story, be wary when repurposing [scripts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/398710/291147)

Comment: @lonix, I've now fixed some of the obvious mistakes in that answer and added a warning comment that you may want to read.

Comment: Thank you Stéphane

Comment: *"anything other than the simplest script, errexit should be avoided"* - I've discovered that multiple times, the hard way, but keep using it because it feels "safe"; I think I'm going to stop using `set -e`